# Python & Selenium Clicking on td value in a row based on another td in the same row

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

I'm trying to find out how to right click on a td based on a value in another td. Starting with the code below was just trying to find an initial cell and click on that value. If I could get that to work I wanted to right click on a value in the same row that has the text "Requested". The table is dynamic so the columns could be in any order. So for example. Find the name "Howard Johnson" and then right click on the requested value in the state column. (see attached image)

The output is - Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\hassong\Documents\Automation\ffox_Change_Create_Save_Stay_Modified.py", line 135, in <module>
    get_all_rows_approval()
  File "C:\Users\hassong\Documents\Automation\ffox_Change_Create_Save_Stay_Modified.py", line 127, in get_all_rows_approval
    cols = row.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr/td[contains(text(), 'Howard Johnson')]")
  File "C:\Users\hassong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 654, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\hassong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\hassong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hassong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //tr/td[contains(text(), 'Howard Johnson')]
```

#### Table html snippet

[image]

## Program

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

base_url =  "https://xxxx.service-now.com/login.do"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# CHG CREATE WITH SAVE AND STAY

driver.get(base_url)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_name")
username.send_keys("xxx")





time.sleep(1)


password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")
password.send_keys("xxxx")

time.sleep(1)

loginBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("sysverb_login")
loginBtn.click()

time.sleep(1)
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#driver = window.maximize()
createnew = driver.find_element_by_id("filter")
createnew.send_keys("Change")
time.sleep(2)
createnew.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.switch_to_frame("gsft_main")
time.sleep(1)

normal_chg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/div[2]/a')
normal_chg.click()

# Create new normal change information
# # Top screen left
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.category"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Hardware")
time.sleep(1)

assigned_to = driver.find_element_by_name("sys_display.change_request.cmdb_ci")
assigned_to.send_keys("lnux100")
assigned_to.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.priority"))
select.select_by_visible_text("2 - High")
time.sleep(1)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.risk"))
select.select_by_visible_text("High")
time.sleep(1)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.impact"))
select.select_by_visible_text("1 - High")
time.sleep(1)

# Top screen right

assigned_to = driver.find_element_by_name("sys_display.change_request.assignment_group")
assigned_to.send_keys("CAB Approval")
assigned_to.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#Middle

short_desc = driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.short_description")
short_desc.send_keys("This is an automated test...")
time.sleep(1)

desc = driver.find_element_by_id("change_request.description")
desc.send_keys("Testing Notes")
time.sleep(1)



# Now save with basic information
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/span/span/nav/div/div[1]/button[2]')
button.click()
save_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[2]')
save_btn.click()
#button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)


# Request Approval
request_app_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="state_model_request_assess_approval"]')
request_app_btn.click()
time.sleep(4)

# scroll down
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs2_list"]/span[3]/span/span[2]')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view

# Approval Tab - Scroll To
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs2_list"]/span[3]/span/span[2]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
time.sleep(3)


#Click on approvers tab
approval_tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabs2_list"]/span[3]/span/span[2]')
approval_tab.click()
time.sleep(3)

def get_all_rows_approval():
    approval_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_table"]/tbody')

    # get all rows in the table
    rows = approval_table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
#    rows = approval_table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval')]")
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr/td[contains(text(), 'Howard Johnson')]")
        cols.click()

get_all_rows_approval()
```

```html
<tbody class="list2_body">
<tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" class="list_row list_odd" style="" sys_id="30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=task_ci&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <span class="sr-only"></span>
   <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
   <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
   </td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="97000fcc0a0a0a6e0104ca999f619e5b" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=97000fcc0a0a0a6e0104ca999f619e5b">Christen Mitchell</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
   <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
   <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
   </td>
   <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" class="list_row list_even" style="" sys_id="34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <span class="sr-only"></span>
   <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
   <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
   </td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="46d96f57a9fe198101947a9620895886" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=46d96f57a9fe198101947a9620895886">Luke Wilson</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
   <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
   <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
   </td>
   <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" class="list_row list_odd" style="" sys_id="b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <span class="sr-only"></span>
   <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
   <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
   </td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="ee826bf03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5de6" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=ee826bf03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5de6">Bernard Laboy</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
   <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
   <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
   </td>
   <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" class="list_row list_even" style="" sys_id="b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=4&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <span class="sr-only"></span>
   <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
   <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=4&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
   </td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="62d78687c0a8010e00b3d84178adc913" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=62d78687c0a8010e00b3d84178adc913">Ron Kettering</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <div class="datex date-calendar" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
   <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
   <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
   </td>
   <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996" class="list_row list_odd" style="" sys_id="bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
   <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <span class="sr-only"></span>
   <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
   <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=bcf168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961996&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=5&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
   </td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="46ca0887a9fe19810191e08e51927ebf" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=46ca0887a9fe19810191e08e51927ebf">Howard Johnson</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
   <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
   <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
   <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
   <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
   </td>
   <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
     </table>
     <a id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_bottom" href="javascript:function(evt){if(evt){evt.stopPropagation();}}"><span class="sr-only">Bottom of table</span></a>
     </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Well , when you do manually right click in the same row , then what happens ?

Comment: To right click you get a menu of choices..I'll attach a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath :

```
//a[text()='Luke Wilson']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[@class='vt']/a
```

Note that based on name **Luke Wilson** , it will give you **requested** hyperlink which you can use to right click.

In case you want that name to be picked by script dynamically :

```
name = Luke Wilson
//a[text()='"+name+"']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[@class='vt']/a
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will give that a shot. Actually I think I can just right click on the name itself which would make it a bit easier

Comment: As you stated that based on `Howard Johnson` name you want to  right click on requested hyperlink. That's why I have given you that xpath.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first one works. The second with the variable doesnt work. Im guessing its having difficulty locating the text maybe because I havent got the formatting correct. Ive had to put the name in double quotes in the variable like so ->  name = 'Luke Wilson'

Comment: Yeah it may be because of single double quotes.

Comment: Accept this answer if it works for you. Please give the credit to the one who helped you.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks cruisepandey!

Comment: @anfield : Thanks. Have a nice day. Thanks to Rajagopalan for support.