# Selenium/Python click on hyperlink in table cell based on value in same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I believe I am having a similar issue to the question [Python & Selenium Clicking on td value in a row based on another td in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595563/python-selenium-clicking-on-td-value-in-a-row-based-on-another-td-in-the-same)

Table layout (I've removed the column data for those that I am not interested in for clarity):

```
<tbody>
<tr class="FontWeightBold">
    <td>Title ID</td>
    <td>Primary Author Last Name</td>
    <td>Title: Edition</td>
    <td>Draft Due</td>
    <td>Final Due</td>
    <td>Est. Trans. Date</td>
    <td>Target Pub. Date</td>
    <td><td>
    <td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="SmartMasterContent_TitleProposalContent_dgProposals_lBookID_0">T276065</span>
    </td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td> 
        <a id="SmartMasterContent_TitleProposalContent_dgProposals_lbAccept_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$SmartMasterContent$TitleProposalContent$dgProposals$ctl02$lbAccept','')">Request ISBN</a>
    </td>
    <td>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="SmartMasterContent_TitleProposalContent_dgProposals_lBookID_1">T276066</span>
    </td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>
        <a id="SmartMasterContent_TitleProposalContent_dgProposals_lbAccept_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$SmartMasterContent$TitleProposalContent$dgProposals$ctl03$lbAccept','')">Request ISBN</a>
    </td>
    <td>..</td>
</tr>
```

Example problem. I want to click on the "Request ISBN" link for the table row where Title ID (first column) is "T276066".

One of the issues I am having is that the id for the link will have the row number appended to it and the record i am looking at could be in any position on the table.

My Python Code snippet

```
Request_ISBN = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="T276066"]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/a[text() = "Request ISBN"]')
```

To try and reduce areas where errors could be generated I have hardcoded the Title ID into the XPath however this will be replaced with a variable once the code works.

What should be the xpath code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about finding `span` with text `T276066` then finding its ancestor `tr` and then drill-down to the relevant `td/a`, see the following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='T276066']/ancestor::tr/td/a[text()='Request ISBN']").click()
```

Comment: Thats excellent. I just needed to remove the closing bracket after T276066 as it was throwing an error. All worked after that